# Navigate to url after subscribe Angular

Tags: angular, router

I see a lot of same questions with mine, but none of them worked for me. So I am trying to navigate to the url after successful subscribing, but it is not navigating to url instead it is again redirecting to beginning.

```
private moveToOverview(): void {
  this.userService.reloadUser().subscribe(() =>  { this.router.navigate(['/wallet'])});
}
```

If I console the data `.subscribe((data) => {console.log(data); // and then navigate to the url})`, it is logging the data but not navigating.

Comment: make sure *'/wallet'* is correctly in your rout path.
In that case I expect that you have something like *yourUrl/wallet*

Comment: What do you understand under "redirecting to beginning"?

Comment: My situation is actually like this: user clicks continue button and it navigates to form which is required,when clicking the submit button  it should navigate to /wallet. but it is redirecting to continue button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private moveToOverview(): void {
  this.userService.reloadUser().subscribe((data) =>  { this.router.navigate(['/wallet'])});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try "navigateByUrl" instead of "navigate"
and make sure your path is correct